# UINavigationBar occasional glitch

Tags: iphone, xcode, uinavigationbar

When I press back twice really quickly on the UINvaigationBar, then the UINavigationBar animates before the view, and then when the view finally animates the bar becomes blank.  When I NSLog(@"",self.navigationItem.title) is prints the correct title. Does anyone have any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: I'm not really sure how you are able to press the button twice. I just tried this on the simulator by double clicking very quickly, but it starts animating after the first click, so the second doesn't appear to have any effect. What is the result when this happens for you? Are you animating the pop of the view?

Comment: From your comments it sounds like you may not actually be going "back" to the same view controller that you left from to begin with. Even if you can press the button twice it definitely should not execute the pop code twice. You could try to remove the back button from the nav bar after the first press to solve this issue, though if you want to post your back button code we can make sure it is actually doing what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this happen when the init/loadView of a view controller that's being pushed takes a non-negligible time- perhaps the viewWillAppear of your new view controller or the viewDidDisappear of the old is taking some time?

Comment: Ya that is what was happening, I was displaying info from a webservice and reloaded data each time the screen was appearing.  To solve this I just reloaded the data before popping the view